# How to retrieve data from the database without knowing the ID number?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlclient

I have a database with 3 values: id, credits, and name.

How can I get the credits of "some name" without knowing the id?

I only want to retrieve the users's credits in C#.

Comment: Something along the lines of `select credits from mytable where name='some name'` is probably what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an exact match with `=`:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE Name = 'some name'
```

Or you could use `LIKE` with `%` wildcards to do a contains:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE Name LIKE '%some name%'
```

Comment: can you explain how to turn this into an integer? i am new to databases

Comment: turn what into an integer, the results? what exactly do you need from this query?

Comment: i need the ammount of credits

Comment: replace `*` with `credits` (`*` will return all the column values). Note that this is SQL, not C#

Comment: how do i put it into an integer though int = //how to run command in c#

Comment: i need to know how to do it programmatically through c# -_- i need something to give me the ammount of credits in c# as an integer